# bash /home/andyman/.bashrc :Permission denied

Tags: bash, bashrc

After doing `chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa` according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9270734/ssh-permissions-are-too-open-error) answer, I cant access my home directory with `cd` and I get the above mentioned `bash /home/andyman/.bashrc :Permission denied` error every time I open a terminal. Also, I can't open any program. I searched for answers but I didn't find something that helped me.
Ok so I tried a couple of things and as I am writing this: I restarted my computer and now it's working again. But I am not sure which permissions I changed or what exactly I did. Can someone tell me where I can find the default permissions and how they should look like?

I use Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 LTS

Comment: To start with, which Linux distro have you installed (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Mint, et al.), & which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] & add that to your question, so all facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our one-way channel to you. All facts about your PC should go in the Question with [edit] as this is a Q&A site, not a general forum, so things work differently here.

Comment: Most likely you've added an extra space and set these permissions to your home directory, like `chmod 600 ~/ .ssh/id_rsa`

Answer (score 0):

The number is a three-digit, octal number.  Each digit, respectively, stands for owner, group, and world.

Each digit can be read, write, execute, or a combination of those, or none.  Zero means none.  Read = 4, write = 2, and execute = 1.  So 7 means read plus write plus execute.  A 7 in the first position means the owner can read, write and execute this file.  Zero in any position means that those users have no permissions to the file.  754 would mean that the owner of the file can read, write, and execute the file.  People in the same group as the owner can read and execute the file, and anyone else can only read the file.

This web site explains it in more detail:
[File Permissions](https://www.maketecheasier.com/file-permissions-what-does-chmod-777-means/)

Comment: I created a new user and it looks like the default permissions are 755, as you can see in this example:  `# ls -l
total 44
drwxr-xr-x 2 rootytooty rootytooty 4096 May 24 17:47 Desktop
drwxr-xr-x 2 rootytooty rootytooty 4096 May 24 17:47 Documents
drwxr-xr-x 2 rootytooty rootytooty 4096 May 24 17:47 Downloads
...
`